# Update records in one table from another only if records match

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am looking to update a column in Patientdemograpics called custom with a column in Patientdemographics2 called custom but only if the columns FirstName LastName and DateofBirth Match in both tables.

```
Update PatientDemographics
Set PatientDemographics.custom = PatientDemographics2.custom       
FROM            PatientDemographics INNER JOIN
                         PatientDemographics2 ON
                         Patientdemographics.FirstName = Patientdemographics2.FirstName and
                         Patientdemographics.LastName = Patientdemographics2.LastName  and 
                         Patientdemographics.DateofBirth = Patientdemographics.DateofBirth
                         where Patientdemographics.FirstName = Patientdemographics2.FirstName and
                         Patientdemographics.LastName = Patientdemographics2.LastName  and 
                         Patientdemographics.DateofBirth = Patientdemographics.DateofBirth
```

Comment: SQL server 2014

Comment: You can save yourself a lot aggravation if you use table aliases with such long table names that are prone to typographical errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the last condition of the `ON` clause:

```
Patientdemographics.DateofBirth = Patientdemographics.DateofBirth
```

it should be:

```
Patientdemographics.DateofBirth = Patientdemographics2.DateofBirth
```

and also you have a **useless** `WHERE` clause since all its conditions are already applied in the `ON` clause.
Also use aliases to make the code simpler and more readable:

```
Update p
Set p.custom = p2.custom       
FROM PatientDemographics AS p INNER JOIN PatientDemographics2 AS p2 
ON
  p.FirstName = p2.FirstName and
  p.LastName = p2.LastName  and 
  p.DateofBirth = p2.DateofBirth
```